# SCNCameraController only controlling rotation

Tags: swift, scenekit

## Understanding SCNCameraController

TLDR; I can make `SCNCameraController` drive my camera rotations, but not translation and roll.

### Background

I want to use SceneKit's camera controller to drive my scene's camera. The reason I want to subclass it is that my camera is on a rig where I apply rotation to the rig and translation to the camera. I do that because I animate the camera, and applying both translation and rotation to the camera node doesn't create the animation I want.

[Demo repo](https://github.com/mortenjust/Camera-Control-Demo)

Nonetheless, a general solution to this specific question could be interesting for a wider audience, since I haven't seen anyone using or understanding the controller.

### Setting up

1. Instantiate my own `SCNCameraController`
2. Set its `pointofView` to my scene's `pointOfView` (or its parent node I guess)

### Using the camera controller

We now want the new camera controller to drive the scene.

1. When interactions begin (e.g. `mouseDown`), call `beginInteraction(_ location: CGPoint, withViewport viewport: CGSize)`
2. When interactions update and end call the corresponding functions on the camera controller

### Actual behavior

It works when I begin/update/end interactions from mouse down events.
It ignores any other event types, like magnification, scrollwheel, which work in e.g. the SceneKit Editor in Xcode. See `MySCNView.swift` in the repo for a demo.
By overriding the camera controller's `rotate` function, I can see that it is called with deltas. This is great.
But when I override `translateInCameraSpaceBy` my print statements don't appear and the scene doesn't translate.

### Expected behavior

I expected SCNCameraController to also apply translations and rolls to the `pointOfView` by inspecting the `currentEvent` and figuring out what to do.

I'm inclined to think that I'm supposed to call `translateInCameraSpaceBy` myself, but that seems inconsistent with how `Begin/Continue/End interaction` seems to call `rotate`.